# Не меняется title в заголовке страницы bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Прошу помощи. 
`require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Каталог");`
пробую менять в коде и в админке, но все безуспешно

Comment: Кеш сбрасывали? Насколько помниться он кэширует страницу целиком!?

Comment: Да, кэш сбрасывал, но все равно ни к чему не приводит

Comment: Тогда согласно документации используйте `$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty('title', 'Page Title');`
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cmain/settitle.php
Я сейчас проверил она работает

Comment: Без сброса кеша

Comment: И надо вызвать её после всех вызовов, то есть конкретно или в конце шаблона или после всех вызовов сет тайтл у модулей

Comment: Сделал по вашему совету, но все равно title не появился

Comment: Хм, может это какой-нибудь баг cms ?

Comment: Потому что действую строго опираясь на документацию

Comment: Попробуйте в конце шаблона прописать, проверить работоспособность

Comment: Вызываемые на странице компоненты также могут вызывать `$APPLICATION->SetTitle`, в итоге будет установлен тайтл из последнего вызова `SetTitle`. Попробуйте по одному убирать компоненты со страницы (если они там есть).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментариях правильно написано, после `$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Каталог");` у тебя есть, скорее всего, вызов компонента и он может менять заголовок. В настройках компонентов посмотри параметры `SET_TITLE` или конструкцию типа `$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Каталог");` нужно разместить ниже, чтобы они переопределяли изменения в компоненте

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло.

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае после $APPLICATION->SetTitle("...") был подключен компонент, в параметрах вывода которого указывалось:

```
"SET_TITLE" => "Y"
```

Заменил на

```
"SET_TITLE" => "N"
```

и проблема ушла.